# calculating the average wining of a jackpot

Tags: probability

you have an urn with balls numbered from 1-90, you guess 6 numbers in your mind, and then pick 6 balls from the urn, if the numbers you guessed match the numbers u picked out in any order, you win the jack pot of 10^7, else you lose 1$, calculate the average wining, also calculate what should the jackpot prize be in order to make the game fair, ( a fair game is where the average wining is 0)

Answer (score 1):

The probability to guess all the $6$ numbers correct, is

$$1\ :\ \binom{90}{6}=622,614,630$$

So, we have $p\approx1.6\cdot 10^{-9}$. The average winning is

$(1-p)\cdot(-1)+pn=(n+1)p-1$ , if we can collect $n$ dollars in the case of a win.

The game is fair, when $n=622,614,629\ \ $ ($1$ less than the number of possibilities)

To see this, denote $S$ to be the number of possibilities. The probability to win is $\frac{1}{S}$. The game is fair, when $(n+1)p-1=0$ So, we have $n=\frac{1}{p}-1=S-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Peter's answer is perfect but an alternative approach to see this is that over 'x' games you want to neither win nor lose anything, and if it is fixed that you lose a dollar every time you lose we can directly say that this can happen only one way,
We lose (x-1) games and win 1 such that the prize money is (x-1)

Again the conclusion is same as that of Peter's